# How to Add a New Row to Multiple dataframes in a List in R

Tags: r

I have a list containing multiple dataframes and I would like to be able to add a new row to each data frame for year

I would like to be able to edit my all my dataframes at the same time, so I started by combining my dataframes into a list

```
df1 <- data.frame (first_column  = c(0),
               second_column = c(1),
               third_column = c(2))
df2 <- data.frame (first_column  = c(3),
               second_column = c(4),
               third_column = c(5))
df3 <- data.frame (first_column  = c(6),
               second_column = c(7),
               third_column = c(8))
df.list<-list(df1,df2,df3)
names(df.list)<-c("df1","df2","df3")
```

Next I would like to add a row for year to every dataframe, like this

| First Column | Second Column | Third Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2000 | 2000 | 2000 |

Though I would like to be able to add different years to different dataframes (2000 to df1, 2001 to df2, 2002 to df3, etc).

I have attempted to create a new row blank for each dataframe using lapply, but this has not been working for me.

```
newlist <- lapply(df.list, function(x) insertRows(x, 2, new = NA)
```

I'm also lost on how to add different years to the new rows for different dataframes once I get the blank rows added to the dataframes. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Map`

```
 Map(rbind, df.list, seq_along(df.list)-1 + 2000)
```

-output

```
$df1
  first_column second_column third_column
1            0             1            2
2         2000          2000         2000

$df2
  first_column second_column third_column
1            3             4            5
2         2001          2001         2001

$df3
  first_column second_column third_column
1            6             7            8
2         2002          2002         2002
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a named list of values to add, with names matching the data frame names

```
add <- list(df2 = rep(2001, 3), df3 = rep(2002, 3))

add
$df2
[1] 2001 2001 2001

$df3
[1] 2002 2002 2002
```

using `sapply` to add each entry to your existing list of data.frames

```
sapply(names(df_list), function(x) rbind(df_list[[x]], add[[x]]), simplify=F)
$df1
  first_column second_column third_column
1            0             1            2

$df2
  first_column second_column third_column
1            3             4            5
2         2001          2001         2001

$df3
  first_column second_column third_column
1            6             7            8
2         2002          2002         2002
```

Comment: I've managed to get my original data working, however now I have non-linear year information (i.e. 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007). The 'seq_along()' is not working in this instance and keeps adding 2003 to the data while excluding 2007. I think the 'list()' function might be the answer, however I'm stuck on what to do after I have created the add object: 'add <- list(df1 = rep(2000, 3), df2 = rep(2001, 3),
            df3 = rep(2002, 3),df4 = rep(2004, 3),
            df5 = rep(2005, 3),df6 = rep(2006, 3) ,df7 = rep(2007, 3))'  Any ideas?

Comment: The `sapply` takes the names of the df's from the df_list and makes them available as `x`. The rows in `add` as list take the names where they should be added in the df_list. So `x` is also the name of the corresponding `add` row, i.e. `add[[x]]`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, I managed to get everything working!